# How to Get the ID field value in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'm new in Odoo 8 and have some difficulties getting the ID value of a object for example the ID field value of hr.employee, can you give me some sample in this matter

Comment: Can you give more detail info?

Comment: @ ThanhLD thanks for the respond to my question I want to get the current Id of the selected record of the hr.employee, I've tried to used the self.id but I can't get the value of the ID field. and for the selected record is when a user triggered the edit or create of information in Employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Official Doc for v8.0](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/) , it will give you clear idea.

For note, if your are using New API then you just directly create model_object and fetch using model_obj.id

As on your example

```
HrEmployee = self.env['hr.employee']
employee_id = HrEmployee.id
```

Comment: This is correct, the only thing here is, you will get false value as no record is been browsed.

Comment: @01010010 01101111 0110 thanks for the reply, how about getting the ID field value when a user triggered the edit or create in Employee Info? I will need the ID field value  for the some sql query in the model